# How to create a dynamic subroutine name in perl

Tags: perl, function, subroutine

I want to create a dynamic subroutine name in perl, Here is trial code , I am getting error "Bad name after feed_load::"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
      push @INC, '/freespace/attlas/data/bin/genericLoader /FeedLoaderLib/'
}

use feed_load;
my type ="L";
my $tempTablefunct  = "Create".$type."Temp_Table";

feed_load::&$tempTablefunct->($tablename); ### pass a dynamic sub name HERE ###
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Actually I have create dynamic  subroutine name for example : "CreateLTemp_Table"  in this place of 'L'  it can come 'P' also ,so it becomes  "CreatePTemp_Table"..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```perl
&{ $pkg_name."::".$sub_name }( @args )
```

or

```perl
( $pkg_name."::".$sub_name )->( @args )
```

These will fail, however, because you asked Perl to forbid you from doing this by placing `use strict;` in your program. You can disable `use strict;` locally.<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
my $ref = do { no strict 'refs'; \&{ $pkg_name."::".$sub_name } };
$ref->( @args )
```

But it turns out that `\&$sub_name` is already exempt from strictures, so you simply need the following:

```perl
my $ref = \&{ $pkg_name."::".$sub_name };
$ref->( @args )
```

---

If instead of sub call you need a method call, you can use

```perl
my $ref = $o->can( $method_name );
$o->$ref( @args )
```

or just

```perl
$o->$method_name( @args )
```

---

1. It's sensible to ask Perl to prevent the use of symbolic references, because it's easy to use one by accident. But here we intend to use a symbolic reference, so it's also sensible to disable strictures where the symbolic reference is used.

Comment: In addition to this, I often do something like `*{ $name } = sub { ... }`. This changes (or creates) the sub in the symbol table, and sometimes that's appropriate for the task.